# Can't update Date field in MySql using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a DATE field in my table, and I'm trying to update it using the following code:

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$todaydate = date("Y-m-d");
$sqlDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($todaydate));
$sql="UPDATE Library SET Loaned=1, LoanedDate=$sqlDate WHERE BookId=$bookId";
$query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

It updates the "Loaned" field fine, but always sets the Date field to "0000-00-00".  Can anyone indicate what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Youre missing `'` quotes in your update query

Just use  something like this

```
$sql="UPDATE Library SET Loaned=1, LoanedDate='$sqlDate' WHERE BookId='$bookId'";
$query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

Comment: This doesn't work in cases where $sqlDate is NULL, so if you don't always have a $sqlDate value then it will fail.  Anyone find a solution for this case?

Answer (score 4):

You must have to add Quotes to the values... other wise the date may seem like an invalid integer to mysql. Here's how:

```
    $query     = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $todaydate = date("Y-m-d", time());  //<== DON'T FORGET THE 2ND ARGUMENT TO date(): TIME-STAMP. YOU MAY USE: time()
    $sqlDate   = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($todaydate));
    $sql       ="UPDATE Library SET Loaned=1, LoanedDate='{$sqlDate}' WHERE BookId='{$bookId}'";
    $query     = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use only MySQL function to update date

Use this

```
$sql = "UPDATE Library SET Loaned = 1, LoanedDate = DATE(NOW()) 
        WHERE BookId = '".$bookId."'";
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your query with this code

```
$sql="UPDATE Library SET Loaned=1, LoanedDate= current_date() WHERE BookId='".$bookId."'";
```

Also check data structure in database.

Answer (score 2):

This query is working fine:

```
$current_date = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$sql = "UPDATE user SET dt_added = '".$current_date."' WHERE id = '$id' ";
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not concatenating the Date string properly in the SQL query.

Use `'` and `.` operator to concatenate the string. Like this,

```
$sql="UPDATE Library SET Loaned=1, LoanedDate='".$sqlDate."' WHERE BookId='".$bookId."'";
```

---

Altough it's good practice to use Prepared statement to pass arguments in SQL query.

[Learn more about PHP Prepared Statements](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)

Comment: Oh my bad, forgot to add `"` at the end. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looking closer, I would just do:

```
$sql="UPDATE Library SET Loaned=1, LoanedDate='".$todaydate."' WHERE BookId='".$bookId."'";
```

instead of

```
$sql="UPDATE Library SET Loaned=1, LoanedDate='".$sqlDate."' WHERE BookId=$bookId";
```

Comment: Why are you concatenating in the first line? Syntax error in your second line.

Comment: @osomanden     You have a typo in here: `LoanedDate={$sqlDate]`. Used closing Square brackets rather than Curly Brace ;-)

Comment: Correct - forgot the '{$sqlDate}'

Comment: The curly brackets are useless around a simple variable.